# Which parts of $S$ these parametrization cover?

Tags: differential-geometry

> Show that the set $S=\{(x,y,z): z=x^2-y^2\}$ is a regular surface and check that parts a and b are parametrizations  for $S$:
>   a. $x(u,v)=(u+v, u-v, 4uv)$ with $(u, v)\in\mathbb{R}^2$
>   b. $x(u,v)=(u\cosh v, u \sinh v, u^2)$ with $(u, v)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $u\not=0$.
>   Which parts of $S$ these parametrization cover?

Show that a and b are parametrizations of $S$ is easy, but I don't know how to solve the final part, the part about what part is covered. How can I get this information?

Thanks!

Comment: At first sight the first parametrisation covers the whole of $S$. It is even a diffeomorphism, so I don't quite understand the question. I believe $S$ is connected so?

Comment: I am so sorry, but I think it should be $u$, if it does not i can undo it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parametrization in a covers the whole of $S$ since we get a unique value for $(u,v)$ for every value of $(x,y)$ and conversely.
The second one, I noticed that that $z$ is positive and so it covers the above sheet only.

Answer (score 0):

Since $z=f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ is a differentiable function and $S$ is the graph of $f$, it follows by proposition 1 of the same book that $S$ is a regular surface.

We now check that $x(u,v)=(u+v,u−v,4uv)$  with $(u,v)\in\mathbb{R^2}$ is a parametrization. Notice that $(u+v)^2-(u-v)^2=4uv$.

Since $u+v, u-v, 4uv$ have continuous partial derivatives, $x$ is $C^\infty$.
Also $dX_q$ is injective for each q as the columns (1, 1, 4v) and (1, -1, 4u) of the matrix $dX_q$ are linearly independent. We only have to show $x$ is injective so that $x$ is a local chart.

Comment: The first column of the matrix is $(1, 1, 4v)$ the 2nd column is $(1, -1, 
 4u)$. As the jocobian determinant is not all zero, the matrix is linearly independent.